# Changing the TimeZone

Tags: cocoa

How to change the time zone from pst8pdt to gmt in cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `NSTimeZone` class.  This interacts with `NSDate` objects in your code.  If you were asking how to change the users timezone, then that is part of their System Preferences, and is best changed in that application.